# My internet is slow for no immediate reason

Tags: router, internet

I live in Denmark and have bought 25/25 Mbps internet for my apartment.

I got a Router that can handle 300/300 Mbps Wi-Fi connections as well as 100 Mbps LAN connections and honestly the internet runs pretty smoothly without any hiccups. However then I started a game updater which downloads at ~3.5 Mbps (Seems capped) and now the rest of my computers internet seems to have been cut down to less than 1 Mbps which I don't quite understand. The downloader does use Peer to Peer. (YouTube starts to stutter and I have to wait for it to load, pages take forever to load, etc)

[image]

(The Above picture is taken from speedtest.net while the downloader is running)

I'm a programmer so I'm fairly tech savvy but perhaps I missed something about networks. Do you have any suggestions as to why my internet is cut down to a crawl when the connection is the speed that it is?

Setup:

- Windows 8.1
- Wired Connection
- [Netgear N300](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-routers/WNR3500L.aspx#tab-techspecs)
- [Maximus VII Impact Motherboard](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/MAXIMUS_VII_IMPACT/)
- Google Chrome, Firefox simultaneously, Steam (Though it's not updating anything), Skype

Comment: Obviously, the "rest of your computer's internet" is _not_ capped to 1Mbps because `speedtest.net` uses your computer's resources to test the available speed (besides the already used resources), right?

Comment: @ClassStacker That's what I'm thinking yes. It doesn't make much sense. So that's why I'm wondering why the rest of my applications gets capped so severely.

Comment: You are not guaranteed 25 Mbps.  I don't see the problem, your current hardware supports 5x faster internet connection then you currently have, so it isn't a hardware or software problem just an **ISP problem**.

Comment: But I only use what appears to be 8 Mbps out of those 25. Yet all my other applications gets capped in internet speed. This shouldn't happen, no? This also only occurs when I update the game. It doesn't happen any other time. Perhaps when using a torrent client.

Comment: How are you determining the speed in these applications precisely?  Torrent clients are notoriously known to be capped by ISPs

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, but why then are the rest of my applications affected too that are not torrent clients?

Comment: Run dslreports.com/speedtest and see if you're having a bufferbloat problem. Bufferbloat can cause high latency and thus a feeling of slowness/lagginess on connections where the total bandwidth of sustained downloads is still fast.

Comment: Are you sure you are downloading at 3.5Mbps and not 3.5MB/s ?